# How to use vtk.js in angular8

Tags: angular9, vtk.js

I try to use vtk.js in my angular cli application and added the vtk.js to my angular-cli.json.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/OpenGL/glsl/vtkVolumeVS.glsl
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type....
```

How can I use a glsl loader in angular8 or angular9?

Comment: Hey .. were you able to solve your issue ?

Comment: Yes, I have done it.

Comment: Can you share how you solved it .. I tried the following https://discourse.vtk.org/t/using-vtk-js-in-an-angular-app/3909 .. I don't understand on how to use vtk.js rules within my angular/webpack infrastructure

Comment: I'll provide to you as github link after upload on it.